# Weird response printed by Network Inspector of Bumble Bee Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

Updated Android Studio to Bumble Bee and wanted to use Network Inspector. Response is no longer plain text. It works well on Network Profiler of Arctic Fox (previous version of Android Studio). I tried to look at update docs but could not find anything in this direction. Is there some setting that needs to be changed?

Android Studio Bumblebee | 2021.1.1 Patch 1

[image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I had the same problem after updating Android Studio to Bumble Bee.
Please set acceptable encodings in the request header. ("Accept-Encoding", "identity")
It works for me.

Comment: Thanks. https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/network-profiler talks about why... But it only mentions about not showing header without it so I did not consider before.

Comment: Thanks, I'm doing this now as well. but only for debug builds (BuildConfig.DEBUG == true). So production builds can still benefit from gzip but during development I can see the responses.